# Having problem reading .xls files in pandas read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I recently started to learn python for data analysis but I can not read the data in [this link](http://new.tse.ir/archive/Trade/Cash/SymbolTrade/SymbolTrade_IRO1FOLD0001.xls)

I use this:

```
import pandas ad pd
df = pd.read_excel('SymbolTrade_IRO1FOLD0001.xls')
```

and I get this error:

> File "C:/Users/kiyan/PycharmProjects/test/test'.py", line 2, in 
>           df = pd.read_excel('SymbolTrade_IRO1FOLD0001.xls')
>
> File "C:\Users\kiyan\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
>           io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
>
> File "C:\Users\kiyan\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 821, in **init**
>           self._reader = self._enginesengine
>
> File "C:\Users\kiyan\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py", line 21, in **init**
>           super().**init**(filepath_or_buffer)
>
> File "C:\Users\kiyan\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py", line 353, in **init**
>           self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
>
> File "C:\Users\kiyan\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
>           return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
>
> File "C:\Users\kiyan\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
>           with open(filename, "rb") as f:
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SymbolTrade_IRO1FOLD0001.xls'

Comment: If you read the file that way without a path, it means that the file sits in the same directory as your script. Is that the case?

Comment: yes but it dosent matter where is the file stored however i try it gives me an error but if i open the file manually and then save  it  again it will be fine